# How to move/Change UV map manually?

Tags: uv

IDK How to ask but "I want to move my UV map parts."
I have some UV like this :

[image: First IMG]

And I want it to be like This :

[image: Changed IMG]

How?
sorry if I ask stupidly.

Note 1: this UVs are hand made to just show the question.
Note 2: it's don't have to be just on blender I have ZBrush too.

tanks.

Comment: When I press G to move the selected part using blender 2.7 on the uv map it jumps the grid it doesn't let me move it smoothly to the edge what can I do to stop that?

Answer (score 4):

In Blender, select the object, enter edit mode, open an UV/Image editor window, press the little icon which lets you select a whole UV Island in just one right click, then you can press G to grab, R to rotate and S to scale your UV island.

[image]